# проблема со счетчиком товара в корзине

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не правильно работает счетчик товара, чем больше товаров тем больше счетчик +-.

Структура кода.

При нажатии кнопки добавить в корзину:

```
$('.btn-add-cart').click(function(e){
createCartElement(); });
```

Идет вызов функции в которой, при каждом нажатии, создается карточка с товаром:

```
out += '<button class="btn-counter minus"><p class="btn-text">-</p></button>';
out += '<input class="counter" value="1">';
out += '<button class="btn-counter plus"><p class="btn-text">+</p></button>';

cartItem.innerHTML = out;
cartItems.append(cartItem);
```

Внутри этой же функции обрабатывается нажатие на кнопки + и - с выводом счетчика:

```
$('.btn-counter.plus').click(function(e) {

  let input = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].value);
  input = input + 1;
  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].value = input;
});

$('.btn-counter.minus').click(function(e) {
  let input = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].value);
  input = input - 1;
  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].value = input;
  if (input == 0) {
    input = 1;
  }
});
```

И так, суть проблемы заключается в том, что при первом нажатии на кнопку (добавить в корзину)- добавляется один товар и все работает хорошо, счетчик добавляет +1 и -1, создали еще одну, старая карточка +2 -2, а новая +1 -1 итд (+3 -3), скорее всего при создании нового элемента оно передает значение старому, прошу помочь с данной проблемой, пробовал уже разные варианты, ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: у вас в `createCartElement()` каждые раз на все `btn-counter` навешиваются события?
Можно вынести в содержимое обработчиков +/- в отдельные функции и создавать кнопки как элементы с присвоением `btn.onclick = funcItemIncrement()`.
Возможно нужно что бы funcItemIncrement возращала fn `() => e=> {}` что бы можно было это делать : `e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children`

Comment: @Gosha, при каждом вызове createCartElement() создается btn-counter, я выносил в отдельные функции и вызывал при клике, происходило тоже самое, возможно я не совсем понимаю, что вы имели ввиду, я просто пока не очень силен в  js, можете дать пример функции ?

Answer (score 0):

это просто пример, но он показывает что надо

```js
const wrapItems = document.querySelector('#list');

const createButton = (isAdd, elementInput) => {
  let operation;
  let cssClass;

  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  if (isAdd === true) {
    operation = '+';
    cssClass = 'plus'
    btn.onclick = () => elementInput.value = parseInt(elementInput.value, 10) + 1;
  } else {
    operation = '-';
    cssClass = 'minus';
    btn.onclick = () => elementInput.value = parseInt(elementInput.value, 10) - 1;
  }
  btn.classList.add('btn-counter', cssClass);

  btn.innerHTML = `<p class="btn-text">${operation}</p>`;

  return btn;
}

document.querySelector('#add-item').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const itemDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.value = 1;
  const btnPlus = createButton(true, input);
  const btnMinus = createButton(false, input);

  itemDiv.append(btnMinus, input, btnPlus);

  wrapItems.appendChild(itemDiv);
});
```

```html
<button id="add-item">add</button>
<div id="list"></div>
```

а еще, если это допустимо, можно использовать 
`<input type="number" step="1" min="0">`

Answer (score 0):

На один и тот же DOM-элемент можно вешать сколько угодно слушателей событий.

Проблема твоего решения в том, что ты вешаешь обработчики события при каждом добавлении нового счетчика, используя при этом общий селектор.

То есть, создал кнопку -> повесил события на все кнопки с селектором .btn-counter.plus.
В твоем случае ход действий получился такой

```
1. Создать счетчик 1
2. Добавить в DOM.
3. Повесить событие на счетчик 1. (1 х1)
4. Создать счетчик 2
5. Добавить в DOM.
6. Повесить событие на счетчик 1 и 2 (1 х2, 2 х1)
7. Создать счетчик 3
8. Добавить в DOM.
9. Повесить событие на счетчик 1, 2 и 3 (1 х3, 2 х2, 3 х1)
```

... и тд.

Есть еще общая проблема с производительностью кода. Добавление через `innerHTML` заставляет лишний раз напрягаться браузерный парсер, чтобы разделить весь текст на токены и сгенерировать исполняемый код.

Лучше упростить задачу браузеру:

```
const createButton = (className, text, clickListener) => {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = className;
    const label = document.createElement('p');
    label.className = 'btn-text';
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    btn.addEventListener('click', clickListener);
    btn.appendChild(label);
    return btn;
};

const createInput = () => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.className = 'counter';
    input.value = 1;
    return input;
};

const createCartElement = () =>
    cartItems.append(
        createButton('btn-counter minus', '-', removeFromCart); // TODO: implement removeFromCart
        createInput(),
        createButton('btn-counter plus', '+', addToCart); // TODO: implement addToCart
    );
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, так мне нужно вынести обработчик из создания элемента корзины ? или все же вешать обработчик во время создания элемента не используя общий селектор ?

Comment: я скорее всего не правильно Вас понял, в какой именно момент нужно создавать счетчик? я создал во время нажатия на добавить товар, сам счетчик работает нормально но при каждом нажатии создается новый счетчик в новом элементе и добавляется в старый, именно верстка, скорее всего мне нужно вынести за область видимости само создание верстки счетчика.

Comment: дело не в создании счетчика, а в том, на какие элементы вешаются обработчики в момент создания счетчика. сейчас у вас события вешаются всегда на все созданные. а надо только на те, которые были созданы прямо сейчас.
Модифицировать ваш код в рабочий будет костыльно, потому что через `innerHTML` вы не имеете ссылок на созданные DOM-элементы. Поэтому придется как-то уродливо их добывать через `.children.slice(-3)` (забрать три последние добавленные ноды, потом из низ забрать кнопки) или что-то подобное. Лучше создавать элементы с помощью  `DOM Api` и сразу вешать обработчики на нужные кнопки

Comment: не могли бы Вы дать пример как это должно выглядеть с помощью DOM Api, я не силен в этом, можно хотя бы наводку?

Comment: `innerHTML` - это тоже часть DOM Api, я некорректно выразил мысль.
Я имел ввиду, создание HTML элементов не через строку в `innerHTML`, а через методы `document.createElement`, `document.createTextNode` и тп.
Просто замените вашу функцию `createCartElement` на код, который я написал выше
Большинство методов управления DOM-элементами находятся на объектах [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document), `Node`, `Element`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: ну я в принципе так и сделал, только не могу понять все же как избавиться от повторного создания счетчика на уже существующем элементе, а сам счетчик работает уже корректно, но с каждым созданием элемента добавляется еще один счетчик ...

Comment: Тогда обновите свой вопрос - укажите темплейт. В своем ответе я описал только момент создания счетчика. Счетчик создается на новодобалвеннном в корзину товаре и работает только относительно своего товара. Почему у вас конкретно при добавление нового элемента, добавляется на существующие, мне без темплейта сложно сказать